# Concatenating adjacent form fields into hidden field value in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, hidden-field

I want to concatenate two form text field values and assign them to my hidden form field in a Rails view:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :shortcode, :value => :package :pins %><br />                                                                                                       

  <div class="field">                                                                                                                                                           
    <%= f.label :package_type %><br />                                                                                                                                          
  <%= select("package", "package_type_id", PackageType.all.collect {|p| [p.packagetype, p.id]} ) %>                                                                             
  </div>                                                                                                                                                                        
  <div class="field">                                                                                                                                                           
    <%= f.label :pins %><br />                                                                                                                                                  
    <%= f.text_field :pins %>                                                                                                                                                   
  </div>
```

I want :shortcode to return the concatenated values of the :package + :pins values entered into their respective form fields.

How do I do that?

Editing to show code used to implement this as the "answer":

```
$('#package_pins').blur(function() {                                                                                                                                        
    var combined = $('select#package_package_type_id option:selected').text() + $('#package_pins').val();                                                                   
    $('#package_shortcode').val(combined);                                                                                                                                  
});
```

Added this code to my "packages.js" in app/assets/javascripts dir.

Note that because the package_type selector is pulling in a belongs_to record in the model, the select options get populated like so:

```
<select id=package_package_type_id name="package[package_type_id]">
<option value="551">FFG</option>
<option value="552">FFC</option>
<option value="553">FTA</option>
</select>
```

where what I wanted to grab from the "FFG" text, rather than the value "551", which is the record id from ActiveRecord, in this case. I was able to do this by using the option:selected').text() jquery code.

Thanks again to @maprihoda for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some client-side Javascript code for this. Using eg JQuery you can easily get the values of the package and pins fields (after the user fills in the pins field), concatenate them, and update the value of the hidden field.

Something roughly like this (you need to add the the right classes to the divs that wrap the fields for this to work):

```
$('selector for the pins field').blur(function() {
  combined = $('selector for the package_type field').val() + $('selector for the pins field').val()
  $('selector for the hidden field').val(combined)
})
```